# ComboBox in DataGridView how to populate another combobox in the second column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Good evening, I have a problem on populating records in DataGridView using DataGridComboBox.

Here's what I wanted but I cant get.

I created `DataGridComboBoxColumn` in `DataGridView1` with 2 Items inside the `ComboBox DropDown` `-"Machine","Materials"`. If I select the `"Machine"` in `ComboBox` column. It will add another `ComboBoxColumn` into next cell with 2 items - `"Machine 1", "Machine 2"`. Also if I select `"Materials"` it will change the items in `"Material 1"` and `"2"`.

Anyone can help me with this much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/717b8819-2340-40e7-a267-04fd73b6ed3e/how-to-filter-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-based-on-selection-of-another-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-in?forum=vbgeneral) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/448621/In-Datagridview-How-to-attach-dataset-to-comboboxc)

Comment: I will check on this sir. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Hi, there is an error on DBGetData("Select....)

Comment: Well mate, with no code to understand your logic, the best help I can offer is providing some useful links to guide you.

Comment: The code in the second link you have provided is the logic that I needed but I cant figure it out where DBGetdata came from.

Comment: The `DBGetData` is not for you. You should replace it with your own. It's a method that executes queries and returns results from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this code.

```
Dim sourceGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView1
Dim targetGrid As DataGridView = Me.DataGridView2

Dim targetRows = New List(Of DataGridViewRow)
For Each sourceRow As DataGridViewRow In sourceGrid.Rows
    If (Not sourceRow.IsNewRow) Then
        Dim targetRow = CType(sourceRow.Clone(), DataGridViewRow)
       For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In sourceRow.Cells
            targetRow.Cells(cell.ColumnIndex).Value = cell.Value
        Next
        targetRows.Add(targetRow)
    End If
Next
targetGrid.Columns.Clear()
For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In sourceGrid.Columns
    targetGrid.Columns.Add(CType(column.Clone(), DataGridViewColumn))
```

Next